# Programmatically increase package weight

Tags: shipping, extensions, export

I'm trying to write some code that will add a fixed amount of weight to orders, to account for packaging material.

I've over-rideden `Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request` with this code, in `app/code/local/Modulename/Shipping/Model/Rate/Request.php`:

```
class Modulename_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request {
    public function setPackageWeight($weight) {
        $weight += 0.23;
        parent::setPackageWeight($weight);
    }
}
```

It's definitely being run, because when I add logging to it, it's showing up in the logs; but when I export the order, I'm just seeing the weight of the actual items showing up.

So I'm clearly doing something wrong, but I don't know what. I figure I'm over-riding the wrong method, or doing so in the wrong way. But I'm stuck trying to figure out what right way of doing this will be.

**Update**

Having been poking around more, it looks like the API access uses a specific model for accessing orders, but I've not been able to figure out which one to over-ride the correct method - it's somewhere under Mage_Sales_Model_Order, I'm sure.

**Update, again**

This is the current config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Modulename_Sales>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Modulename_Sales>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order>Modulename_Sales_Model_Order</order>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked the `Mage_Shipment_Model_Shipment` and it seems that the shipment gets the weight from the order. So basically what you could do is overwrite the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` class and define the `getWeight` method, adding the extra weight when requested.

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Sales_Model_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order
{
   public function getWeight()
   {
       $weight = (float)$this->getData('weight');
       foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $_item)
       {
          $weight += 0.23 * (float)$_item->getOrderedQty();
       }
       return $weight;
   }
}
```

*disclaimer: extremely untested code, don't use this in a live environment*

Comment: Huh. I've been over-riding setWeight all this time. I wonder if that might have been causing issues? I've tweaked the code to use getWeight instead, but it looks like it's not actually been called at all. I've added the config.xml to the question - can you see if there's something hideously wrong with it?

Comment: Hm, not sure. Naming the extension `Sales` might cause a conflict. You're class is placed in `Modulename/Sales/Model/Order.php`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I've added the class, and it's being picked up correctly; when I add a `__construct` function with some logging, then that's being run and I can see the output. But the `getWeight` function isn't being called at all, so I'm assuming I've messed something up - could `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::getWeight` be over-ridden elsewhere, perhaps?

Comment: yes that could very well be it. Log the get_class($order) in the `Mage_Shipment_Order_Shipment` to see what class is actually being used

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to update the existing catalog fully that is there (assuming each weight being fed in from now on will included the package weight) just run some sql direct on the DB to update all that is there. Create a file in root, e.g. /weightupdate.php and run the code you need. Be sure to run on test area 1st, and have a backup DB of that test area before running. It would read something like:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once('app/Mage.php');

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$count = 0;

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach ($products as $product)
{
if ($product->getWeight() > 0)
{
    continue;
}

$count++;

$this->products->getProducts();
{
    $item->setWeight($item->getWeight() + 0.23);

    try
    {
        $item->save();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
  }    
}

echo "Updated {$count} products.";

?>
```

This may need slight editing before running, based on something similar I ran a few months ago.

Comment: I think OP wants to add a specific weight to each shipment to compensate for packaging weight

Comment: Yeah, the above should cover that. Adding 0.23kg to each sku. Alternatively, you could export every SKU, and manually add the needed amount on in excel, but this is a short term messy, probably time consuming solution. If you have a small catalog of a few hundred products or less, it might do the job you need.

Comment: @SanderMangel - I do indeed. We have various products weighing an ounce or so, and the packaging material weights about 2 ounces. We don't want to add the packaging weight onto individual products, but only as a single extra weight on every order.

Comment: Gotcha, assumed each item would be packed individually. See what you mean now. Bit more complex I suppose. You'd had to create something in the sales_order area.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this from overriding

```
class Rehman_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request
{   
    public function setPackageWeight($weight) {
       $weight += 1;
       parent::setPackageWeight($weight);
    }
}
```